# SQL Database Updating not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code to for the edit function. When I enter the values it does not show any error but it does not save the new values in the database . both the INSERT and UPDATE commands are not not working.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Omer\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WAPPassignment\\App_Data\\LoginStuff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader dr;


protected void imgbtnENFN_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    pnENFN.Visible = false;
    lblENFN.Text = txtENFN.Text;
}


protected void imgbtnENLN_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    pnENLN.Visible = false;
    lblENLN.Text = txtENLN.Text;
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
   // cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE WhatTypes SET [First Name]='" + lblENFN.Text + "',[Last Name]='" + lblENLN.Text + "',[TP Number]='" + lblNTPn.Text + "',Email='" + lblENEm.Text + "',UserName='" + lblENUN.Text + "',Password='" + lblENP.Text + "',UserLevel='"+ lblEUL.Text+"Where UserName='" + txtAEUNS.Text+"')", con);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into WhatTypes([First Name], [Last Name], [TP Number], Email, UserName, Password, UserLevel) Values ('" + lblENFN.Text + "','" + lblENLN.Text + "','" + lblNTPn.Text + "','" + lblENEm.Text + "', '" + txtEUN.Text + "', '" + lblENP.Text + "','" + lblEUL.Text+"'Where UserName = '"+txtAEUNS.Text+"' )", con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: your query is wrong.How come you add where clause in insert.Insert is a new instance and u cant use where in it.

Comment: I would suggest you go back to a SQL tutorial. You are trying to combine an `INSERT` with a `WHERE`.

Comment: Ok, now im trying to work on update statement, but it also doesn't update the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void cmdInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string InsertQuery="Insert into WhatTypes([First Name], [Last Name], [TP Number], Email, UserName, Password, UserLevel) "+
        " Values (@fname,@lname,@tpNumber,@email,@userName,@password,@userLevel)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery,con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname",lblENFN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname",lblENLN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tpNumber",lblNTPn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",lblENEm.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName",txtEUN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",lblENP.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userLevel",lblEUL.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
protected void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string InsertQuery = "UPDATE WhatTypes SET [First Name]=@fname,[Last Name]=@lname,"+
        "[TP Number]=@tpNumber,Email=@email,Password=@password,UserLevel=@userLevel Where UserName=@userName";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", lblENFN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lblENLN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tpNumber", lblNTPn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", lblENEm.Text);
    //you do not update username
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtEUN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", lblENP.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userLevel", lblEUL.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtAEUNS.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: This query is not works for insert. see my answer,@Srinivas,@Upvote MarkAnswer

Comment: hmm it is creating the new row in the database . but I want to edit the previous values

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into WhatTypes([First Name], [Last Name], [TP Number], Email,  UserName, Password, UserLevel) Values ('" + lblENFN.Text + "','" + lblENLN.Text + "','" + lblNTPn.Text + "','" + lblENEm.Text + "', '" + txtEUN.Text + "', '" + lblENP.Text + "','" + lblEUL.Text+" )", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: @user2625486, you are using wrong query during insertion. So remove where condition it works because you are making condtion same thing that was not in table.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
   // cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE WhatTypes SET [First Name]='" + lblENFN.Text + "',[Last Name]='" + lblENLN.Text + "',[TP Number]='" + lblNTPn.Text + "',Email='" + lblENEm.Text + "',UserName='" + lblENUN.Text + "',Password='" + lblENP.Text + "',UserLevel='"+ lblEUL.Text+"Where UserName='" + txtAEUNS.Text+"')", con);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into WhatTypes([First Name], [Last Name], [TP Number], Email, UserName, Password, UserLevel) Values ('" + lblENFN.Text + "','" + lblENLN.Text + "','" + lblNTPn.Text + "','" + lblENEm.Text + "', '" + txtEUN.Text + "', '" + lblENP.Text + "','" + lblEUL.Text+"')", con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you  should put ')' before where

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlParameter` for setting variables into sql command, it's more safer and easy readable than string concat. In this case, you got an error on sql string before where statement.  And keeping connection string on config file, and doing operation in try catch block and close connection on finally block is elegant way. By the way omit the `WHERE` statement on `INSERT` block.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your cmd statement with

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into WhatTypes([First Name], [Last Name], [TP Number], Email, UserName, Password, UserLevel) Values ('" + lblENFN.Text + "','" + lblENLN.Text + "','" + lblNTPn.Text + "','" + lblENEm.Text + "', '" + txtEUN.Text + "', '" + lblENP.Text + "','" + lblEUL.Text + "') Where UserName = '" + txtAEUNS.Text + "'", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
   // cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE WhatTypes SET [First Name]='" + lblENFN.Text + "',[Last Name]='" + lblENLN.Text + "',[TP Number]='" + lblNTPn.Text + "',Email='" + lblENEm.Text + "',UserName='" + lblENUN.Text + "',Password='" + lblENP.Text + "',UserLevel='"+ lblEUL.Text+" Where UserName='" + txtAEUNS.Text+"'", con);
    //remove comment for update statement
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into WhatTypes([First Name], [Last Name], [TP Number], Email, UserName, Password, UserLevel) Values ('" + lblENFN.Text + "','" + lblENLN.Text + "','" + lblNTPn.Text + "','" + lblENEm.Text + "', '" + txtEUN.Text + "', '" + lblENP.Text + "','" + lblEUL.Text+"')", con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just like your command. hope it may help.You can use Command Parameters as:

```
string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO table (name, information, other) 
                     VALUES (@name, @information,@other)";
db.Open();

try
{
SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, db.Connection);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@name", info);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@information", info1);
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@other", info2);
cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmdIns.Dispose();
cmdIns = null;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
}
finally
{
db.Close();
}
```